# File upload issue; XMLHttpRequest (XHR) is never called and upload is stuck at 100%

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Tiny File Manager as a starting point for my project:
https://tinyfilemanager.github.io/

To test the functionalities, I have it setup on a Ubuntu (16.04.7) web server running under Apache 2 with PHP 7.0.33.

I have a folder with a few test files, all zip files, all with the exact same permissions but different sizes.

The bigger files (1.4MB to 4MB) get uploaded no problem but the smaller ones (0.4MB to 0.9MB) get stuck at 100% and the Ajax call is just never made at all.

```
progress: 95.84140911112453 | 523665 index.php:139:22
progress: 100 | 546387 index.php:139:22
progress: 95.84140911112453 | 523665 index.php:139:22
progress: 100 | 546387
```

The result in Firefox is Server responded with 0 code.
and in Chrome: Error: Server Timeout

I can manually extract the zip files, so not corrupted. The bigger files can be uploaded so it's not a file size limit issue either.
The code is simple enough and I didn't even change it

HTML

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . '?p=' . fm_enc(FM_PATH) ?>" class="dropzone card-tabs-container" id="fileUploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo fm_enc(FM_PATH) ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="fullpath" id="fullpath" value="<?php echo fm_enc(FM_PATH) ?>">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>
    Dropzone.options.fileUploader = {
        timeout: 120000,
        maxFilesize: <?php echo MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE; ?>,
        acceptedFiles : "<?php echo getUploadExt() ?>",
        init: function () {
            this.on("sending", function (file, xhr, formData) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(formData);
                let _path = (file.fullPath) ? file.fullPath : file.name;
                document.getElementById("fullpath").value = _path;
                console.log(_path);
                xhr.ontimeout = (function() {
                    toast('Error: Server Timeout');
                });
            }).on("success", function (res) {
                let _response = JSON.parse(res.xhr.response);
                if(_response.status == "error") {
                    toast(_response.info);
                }
            }).on("error", function(file, response) {
                toast(response);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on please?

Comment: looks like I'm not the only one being speechless.
Meanwhile, I've been looking at a way to way to have in depth logging on the Apache side but I do not see the individual transactions with the server.
"someone" in the system has got to log something somewhere.

Comment: Update on the issue and I REALLY need the community's help please.
I built a stand alone physical server, installed Ubuntu 18.04, LAMP and created the most basic file upload code possible.
If I try to upload a file that is LESS than 1MB, the upload fails (Connection reset). 
Let's say the file is a zip. If I add content to that zip file to make it bigger than 1MB, the upload works just fine.
I have tried with multiple files, multiple browsers and multiple servers.
I see nothing related to minimum file sizes.
Please help